How do I configure the buffer size for `std::cout` in a portable way?
After disabling synchronization with the C standard library stdio using std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false), how do I change the buffer size for std::cout in a portable way?
I thought I could do this using std::cout.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(..), but testing with GCC 7.x on Linux with the strace tool showed that this wasn't having an effect (the writev system calls were not using the increased buffer size I set).  The documentation for pubsetbuf states that this method may have no effect - so this is consistent.
The non-portable workaround I found was to use the __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf class like so:
static __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char>> standard_output_buf(1, std::ios_base::out, 65536);

std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
std::cout.rdbuf(&standard_output_buf);


Related: increase buffer for cout

Are there any observable changes to the C++ abstract machine behavior caused by your buffer size change?  I actually think not.  So I think any method to do so would have to admit that it could have no effect.  Now, practically, it has an effect - so are you asking for a practically portable way, or a theoretically portable way?  And if practically portable, which platforms?

pubsetbuf calls setbuf, which is specified to have no effect in the base class.

If you need better performance, I would argue that it is already very performant.
